# Waitforseconds is not waiting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code which is loaded when you finish a game level. It should freeze the time, scale the level completed message, wait 5 seconds and then load next level and unfreeze time. The problem is that the WaitForSeconds is not working. It just loads the next level without waiting. What am I doing wrong?

```
IEnumerator WaitingFunction(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
}

void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider col )
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        lvlcomplete.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);

        StartCoroutine(WaitingFunction());

        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        lvlcomplete.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel+1);
        player.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0.3519309f, -2.381933f);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You start a coroutine that waits 5 seconds without doing anything while the OnTriggerEnter code continues to load the level instantly.

You should move the code that should run after the wait time has passed inside the coroutine:

```
IEnumerator WaitingFunction(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    lvlcomplete.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel+1);
    player.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0.3519309f, -2.381933f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i just realized that the WaitForSeconds does not work when the timeScale is set to 0, so i will have to figure out another way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by timeScale is set to 0? Please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Like LearnCocos2D said you have to move the code. Further on to get this working with `timeScale = 0` you simply need to let this wait for the corresponding number of frames:

```
IEnumerator WaitingFunction(){
    int noOfFramesToWait = (int)(seconds * Application.targetFrameRate);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfFramesToWait; i++) {
        yield return null;
    }
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    // do my stuff
}
```

If you have a couple of situations like pausing, additive level loading, game over, fading in and out,.. the next step can be get this more generic:

```
void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider col ) {
    if (col.tag == "Player") {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        StartCoroutine (WaitForNFrames (5f, LoadNewLevel));
    }
}

public void LoadNewLevel () {
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    // do my stuff
}

IEnumerator WaitForNFrames (float seconds, System.Action executeWhenFinished) {
    int noOfFramesToWait = (int)(seconds * Application.targetFrameRate);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfFramesToWait; i++) {
        yield return null;
    }
    executeWhenFinished ();
}
```

---

Another small thing, maybe you have this already: You reference the player object after calling LoadLevel. Ensure that it is not destroyed when the new level is loaded by using DontDestroyOnLoad.

Answer (score -2):

Try restructuring your code as follows

```
WaitingFunction(){
    yield WaitForSeconds (5);
}

void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider col )
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        lvlcomplete.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);

        StartCoroutine(WaitingFunction());

        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        lvlcomplete.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel+1);
        player.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0.3519309f, -2.381933f);

                }
```

Comment: You have not fixed anything. Frankly, you have not even changed much. Look at @LearnCocos2D answer, it should work.